# How do I stop mousePressed in Java 7 (line from continuing to be drawn) when I go to use a JButton

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have a class which is called by a JButton drawline .The code below allows a line to be drawn on a Jpanel by creating the a line point by point and storing each point to an ArrayList. I have only implemented mousePressed event which allows the line to be drawn

The problem I have is when I click another button I have called saveToFile button The line saves to a CSV file (ptID, x, y)  which is what I want, but when I click back in the JPanel the line that is drawn still continues to be drawn with every mouse click.

I had set the pts arrayList to be null in the SaveToFile button after the line is written to CSV file.

I am not sure how I can get the mousepressed event to  stop writing a point to the arrayList when I have clicked the JButton saveToFile?

I had read somewhere that an event could be deactivated which is not a good idea

I was wondering if

1. I need to empty the arrayList Pts and repaint after I 
   saveToFile  so the line is removed from screen when I repaint?
2. Any other ways I could use to stop mousePressed from still occurring
   once I have clicked on the saveLine button

Apologies if this is trivial. I am learning Java and Swing.

class DrawLine implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            try{

```
           addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

              public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

              int yCoord = HEIGHT - e.getYCoord();
              int xCoord = e.getXCoord();

              String pointxy = "p" + x + "," +  y;
              Point p = new Point(pointxy);
              pts.add(p);                                
              repaint();

          }


        });
      }
      // catch stuff done here

     }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try re-instantiating your ArrayList pts in the SaveToFile button method after the pts are sent to the csv. If you would like to keep the line, then you may want to look into building a 2D arraylist:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> pts;
```

and adding a new ArrayList every time the SaveToFile button is pressed to the 2D arraylist.

Comment: Hi llamaCaraDara, unfortunately reinstantiating teh pts ArrayList in the SaveToFile button did not work, after repaint(). When I click on the JPanel the line that seemed like it had been removed reappears and adds a new point to the line where the new mouse pointer click happened

Comment: What is the scope of this ArrayList?

Comment: The ArrayList is local to SaveToFile and then I set it to the global arrayList

Comment: Make sure that you are setting the global arraylist to the new ArrayList, and not the local one